# How to use wstring find/replace for a case insensitve replacement?

Tags: c++, case-insensitive, wstring

This code works perfect for string replacement, but it is case sensitive, which is what I need it to be:

```cpp
WCHAR *StringReplaceEx(CONST WCHAR *orig, CONST WCHAR * pattern, CONST WCHAR  *repl, WCHAR *sOut)
{
    wstring wsoriginal = orig;
    wstring wspatterntofind = pattern;
    wstring wsreplacement = repl;
    wstring wsOut = string_replace(wsoriginal, wspatterntofind, wsreplacement);

    StringCchCopy(sOut, wcslen(wsOut.c_str())+1, wsOut.c_str());

    return sOut;
}

wstring string_replace( wstring src, wstring const& target, wstring const& repl)
{
    if ((target.length() == 0) || (src.length() == 0))
        return src;
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (;;) 
    {
        idx = src.find( target, idx);
        if (idx == wstring::npos)  
            break;

        src.replace( idx, target.length(), repl);
        idx += repl.length();
    }
    return src;
}
```

This works excellently, but only if the string cases match.

Is there a way to do a case-insensitive replacement?

Comment: I don't think there is a definition of case-insensitive for most of the character sets represented by Unicode.

Comment: @RichardCritten -- there is a Unicode table that maps lowercase, uppercase, and titlecase characters. It can be used to implement case-insensitive operations on Unicode. However, Unicode support in C++ is rather poor, and you'll have to implement it yourself, most likely using a third party Unicode library.

Answer (score 0):

By using boost, even though it is outside the scope of the question, fixed the issue for me.